# On Views and Indexes (SQL Server 2008 R2)

Tags: sql-server, view, indexing

I have created a series of views that operate on a fairly large table. The table has been properly indexed and the performance is entirely sufficient. I would like to add an additional layer of views to the DB that are effectively views of views. What I want to know is whether SQL Server is smart enough to use the indexes on the underlying table when it builds the query, or whether I need to index the first tier of views somehow?

Comment: This can be easily checked with the Execution Plan Display

Comment: The actual data will be taken from the tables or view that contain the data physically. Thus Sql server engine has nothing to do except to use all available speed boosters, i.e. indeces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is. A view (not persisted) is nothing more than a query stored on your DB. If you have a view called view1 as select * from table1 and do select * from view1, SQL Server will automatically transform that to select * from table1 and then build a execution plan

Same rule applies if you increase the chain of objects adding more views.